# Error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

Tags: matlab

m =am getting the error"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts" in the following code:

```
S=size(C);
S1=size(k);


p=S(1)+S1(1)-1;
q=S(2)+S1(2)-1;

T=uint8(zeros(S(1)+2*(S1(1)-1),S(2)+2*(S1(2)-1)));

T(S1(1):S1(1)+S(1)-1,S1(2):S1(2)+S(2)-1)=C;


for i=1:p
for j=1:q
mat=k.*C(i:i+S1(1)-1,j:j+S1(2)-1);

    D =sum(mat(:));

end
end
```

please help,the error is in the line:
 **T(S1(1):S1(1)+S(1)-1,S1(2):S1(2)+S(2)-1)=C;**

If more details required kindly ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both `S` and `S1` are `[1 x 2]` arrays (that is, if C and k are 2D matrices).
`T(S1(1):S1(1)+S(1)-1,S1(2):S1(2)+S(2)-1)=C;` creates some matrix, based on the actual values of `S` and `S1`. This array apparently is not the same size as `C` and you can therefore not assign this array to `C`.

On a sidenote: why are there asterisks around the line where you assign `T`? Matlab does not recognise that as valid code and if it only is a highlight as a visual aid for us, the reader, it's better to remove it so we can actually run the code.

Comment: yes the double asterisk were to notify the line...which i have removed now.N many thanks for your suggestions,m trying on it..

Comment: If you add the values of C and S1 (or samples of them if they are large) everyone can try this code and help you to fix it.